# datestr returns multiple column char matrix instead of one column

Tags: matlab, date

I have the following simple code:

```
conn = yahoo('http://download.finance.yahoo.com');
IBM = fetch(conn,{'IBM'},{'Adj Close'}, '2012-01-01','2015-08-01','d');
MO = fetch(conn,{'MO'},{'Adj Close'}, '2012-01-01','2015-08-01','d');

%IBM = [datestr(IBM(:,1),2) IBM(:,2)]
%MO = [datestr(MO(:,1),2) MO(:,2)]
```

The last two lines give me an error. datestr is returning a char matrix with 8 columns! 1 column per number of the date, [0,1,0,1,2,0,0,1]! How do I get the output to be 1 column?

Comment: What is the content of the variables `IBM` and `MO` before running the last two lines? What output do you expect after the last two lines?

Comment: IBM[date as serial number, closing price] and i'd like [date 'dd/mm/yy' format  , closing price]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider accepting the answer (green check mark on the left) to mark the problem as solved, if it is. Otherwise please clarify your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want a **cell array** instead of a **char matrix**, so just use [**`cellstr`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellstr.html) for the conversion.

```
IBM = cellstr([datestr(IBM(:,1),2)])
MO = cellstr([datestr(MO(:,1),2)])
```

respectively:

```
IBM = {cellstr([datestr(IBM(:,1),2)]) IBM(:,2)}
MO = {cellstr([datestr(MO(:,1),2)]) MO(:,2)}
```

Maybe a `table` is what you want:

```
T = table( datestr(IBM(:,1),2), IBM(:,2), datestr(MO(:,1),2), MO(:,2),...
           'VariableNames', {'IBM_T','IBM_VAL','MO_T','MO_VAL'})

T = 

     IBM_T      IBM_VAL      MO_T      MO_VAL
    ________    _______    ________    ______

    07/31/15    161.99     07/31/15     54.38
    07/30/15    160.96     07/30/15      54.2
    07/29/15    161.09     07/29/15      54.4
    07/28/15    160.05     07/28/15     55.25
    07/27/15    159.07     07/27/15     53.95
    07/24/15    159.75     07/24/15     53.79
    07/23/15    161.73     07/23/15     53.82
    07/22/15    160.35     07/22/15     53.96
    07/21/15    163.07     07/21/15     53.55
    07/20/15    173.22     07/20/15     53.71
    07/17/15    172.51     07/17/15     53.22
    ...
```

This video about [**Using Tables for Financial Data**](http://www.mathworks.com/videos/using-tables-for-financial-data-88253.html) may is also interesting for you.

Comment: No, it doesn't give me an error but it just spits out gibberish. It's currently in this form [786838 100.00] and i just want [01/01/10 $100.00], 2 column matrix

Comment: @user2977664, you cannot mix types in a standard matrix. The result of `datestr` will be a `string` (=array of `char`), while the price is a `double` (a numeric value). Only `cell arrays` can contain elements of different type. Or you have to convert everything to string/char if you want it in the same matrix. By the way, you should include the information from your comment above in your original question.

Comment: How do people work with stock prices which include a numeric value and date?

Comment: @user2977664 They use cell arrays, structs or tables